# Hi, Excel question. 10 companies with each has a multiple rows of monthly sales values. Months are common. I want to graph all on one graph. How?

Tags: excel, sorting, graph, sum, unique-values

Excel question. 10 companies with each has a multiple rows of monthly sales values. It depends where each company starts, there could be months in common. I would like to have all values on one single graph that will sum up the monthly sales values of all companies. I could do it manually but it would take forever and especially when each company could have rows for many years. Thanks

I tried YOUTube with no luck.

Comment: Please give us an example of your data and expected output. If your data is sensitive, just make something up.

Comment: column chart with each company represented.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use formulas to create a staging table that has the desired aggregation per month and company, then use that staging table as the chart source. In general, Excel charts don't summarize data. You will need to do that kind of preparation work yourself.

Create a table with company names in the columns and the months as the rows, then use formulas to calculate a company's total for the given month. How exactly this formula is constructed cannot be suggested, since you did not include any sample data.